# i am facing GridDB Sync Data and Libraries Error?

Tags: database, griddb

I am not sure what is causing this error, and I have not been able to find a solution online.

```
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactoryOptions;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.PartitionController;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.SubnetGridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.common.GSErrorCode;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.common.GridStoreFactoryProvider;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStoreFactoryProvider;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetPartitionController;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetPartitionControllerConfig;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetPartitionControllerContext;

public class GridDBSyncDataAndLibraries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridStoreFactoryOptions options = new GridStoreFactoryOptions();
        GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactoryProvider.get(options);
        GridStore store = null;
        try {
            String url = "griddb://localhost:31810/defaultCluster/public";
            store = factory.getStore(url);
            // Sync data and libraries here
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (store != null) {
                store.close();
            }
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to troubleshoot this error by checking if I have the latest version of GridDB installed and if all the required libraries are available. I have also tried to reinstall GridDB, but the error still persists. I was expecting the code to sync data and libraries without any error.